# Read a text file and assign values to variables

Tags: java

Java beginner here but I am sincerely trying. The goal of this program is to read two values from the Realtor11.txt file and assign them to variables.

The contents of Realtor11.txt is (no spaces):

John

100

See section // Read Realtor11.txt Not sure what I'm doing wrong but currently the error is

Realtor11.java:48: error: incompatible types
            price = in.readLine();
                               ^
  required: double
  found:    String
1 error
Error: Could not find or load main class Realtor11
[Finished in 1.1s]

```
// java class for keyboard I/O
import java.util.Scanner;
// java class for JOption GUI
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
// File reader
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Realtor11
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    // Keyboard and file input
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); 
        Scanner inputStream = null;
    // price of the house, the cost to sell the house and the commission
        double price, cost, commission;
    // seller’s name
        String seller; 

    // GUI diplay message declaration
        String display_message = "This program calculates the cost to sell a home\n" 
        + "and the commission paid to an individual sales agent.\n\n"
        + "The user is asked for the last name of the seller and the\n"
        + "sales price.\n\n";

    // Output descriptive messages
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, display_message, "Lab 1 Description", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    // Read Realtor11.txt
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Realtor11.txt"));
            while (in.read()!= -1);
            seller = in.readLine();
            price = in.readLine();
            in.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {}

    // calculate the cost and the commission
        cost = 0.06 * price;
        commission = 0.015 * price;
    // display the input and results
        String 
            out1 = String.format("%nThe " + seller + "’s" + " home sold for $%.2f%n", price),
            out2 = String.format("The cost to sell the home was $%.2f%n", cost),
            out3 = String.format("The selling or listing agent earned $%.2f%n", commission);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, out1 + out2 + out3, seller + "'s Home Sale", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    // Output to file
    // still writing this. 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `readLine()` returns a `String` value where you're expecting a `double` value ([see API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)).  You must convert the `String` value to a `double` as so:

```
price = Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
```

Comment: Thank you ! I had no idea I could do that. I read the Oracle docs and did not find this kind of syntax.

Comment: No problem.  Just remember you have to convert when needed.  Also, if you found this answer to be correct, mark it correct as so:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

the readline() function returns a string. What you would need to do is to manually convert that price string to a double 
    double price = Double.parseDouble(string version of price);